# Simple one: php explode not outputting expected results

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

Ok, so for this simple php function:

```
$FBIDs = "1,15,16,18,30";
$FBArr = explode(",", $FBIds);
```

print_r($FBArr);

The output is:

```
Array ( [0] => )
```

Am I doing something wrong? Am I blind? Why isn't this giving me an array with the numbers as elements? This is driving m nuts!

Comment: case sensitive: `$FBArr = explode(",", $FBIDs);`

Answer (score 4):

The variable you're trying to explode is `$FBIDs`, but you're exploding `$FBIds`; The final "d" needs to be capitalized and it should work.

Comment: Ha, this is why I shouldn't program at midnight.

Comment: Case-sensitivity, the bane of many PHP programmers =P. To help finding issues like this, consider (temporarily) turning on error-reporting for everything: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`. This will show you the "undefined" variables as NOTICE-errors.